# How to automate Facebook game usign sikuliapixand Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, sikuli, sikuli-script, facebook-instant-games

I am having the latest sikuliapix and Selenium WebDriver dependencies in my maven project, and I am trying to automate a Facebook game. As of now I am in the level screen of the Candy Crush game and want to click on the level 2 icon or either level 1 icon, but sikuli fails to recognize the image which I have already in the project folder.

I am including those screenshots and the code here. Here is the Facebook game link: https://apps.facebook.com/candycrush/

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class AutomatingFbGame {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\jenny 
howard\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");


ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);


driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

   driver.manage().window().maximize();

   driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("xxxxxx@gmail.com");

   driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("xxxxxx");


   driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();

   Screen s = new Screen();

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navItem_210831918949520']/a/div")).click();

  Pattern p2 = new Pattern("l2.png");

    s.find(p2);
    s.doubleClick(p2);

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [**`Facebook Graph API`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Comment: Facebook was just an example , I am trying to use a html5 game and other online games to practice with , so any guidance for scripts will be helpful

Comment: Can you expand on what problem in particular you are having with your scrape? When you say "sikuli fails to recognize the image", have you tried to print out the relevant bit of HTML, to see if it is selecting it correctly?

Comment: I didnt understand your question sir :/ @halfer